# Handling odd request formats with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a site that is receiving requests for URLs in odd formats (for instance :formats=>[:"application/youtube-client", :"*/*"])

However, as we don't have this in the app (it's all HTML) how do we handle these requests without returning an error or suchlike.  Is there any way of defaulting everything to HTML?

Comment: Get a working solution to this?